# Evitar que R cree ficheros R.Data y R.History

Tags: r

Tengo un script creado en `R` y cada vez que se ejecuta me deja en la carpeta dos archivos, un .Rdata y un .RHistory.

He puesto esto al final de mi script, pero no funciona ya que se ve que crea los archivos una vez finaliza.

```
if (file.exists(".RData") == TRUE) {
  file.remove(".RData")
}
if (file.exists(".Rhistory") == TRUE) {
  file.remove(".Rhistory")
}
```

He de decir que soy bastante nuevo en esto.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Inicia R en modo `--no-save`. Consulta `R --help`.

Puedes agregar esto a tus accesos directos (en Windows, por ejemplo, de la siguiente forma en propiedades)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fuente: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098189/disable-saving-history)

Comment: Hola, 

Gracias por tu comentario. Estoy usando un script programado con el programador de tareas de windows. 

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se inicie en modo --no save?

Comment: Sin ver el script es difícil decirte, pero cuando llamas al programa le indicas la ruta, verdad? Pues allí es donde debes añadirle el `--no-save`.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es correr un Script de una forma no iteractiva, la manera adecuada o indicada es hacerlo mediante el comando [`Rscript`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.0/topics/Rscript). Este comando forma parte de todas las distribuciones `R` y por defecto no salva el entorno al salir como normalmente puede llegar a hacerlo la versión interactiva tipo `Rgui` o `Rstudio`. La ejecución no reviste demasiada complejidad:

```
Rscript.exe Script.R # En windows
Rscript Script.R # En Linux
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. 

Ahora solamente me falta configurar bien el programador de windows. 

Antes tenía como Programa `R.exe` y lo he cambiado a `Rscript.exe` y tengo como argumento `CMD BACTH` y la ruta del script. Pero no me funciona cuando ejecuto la tarea.

¿Qué me falta?

Comment: Al final lo he conseguido con `--no-save` como comentaba `@zeross`
En el programador de tareas de Windows he dejado `R.exe` y en el argumento, detrás del `CMD BACTH` he añadido el `--no-save`. ¿Hay alguna forma mejor o me quedo con esta?